# Where to find info/changelogs of ROS package releases

Tags: ros, package, ros-kinetic, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and get updates of ros-packages from time to time via apt(-get). One can observe that they're released in "bursts", so a group of packages are released together.
Everytime I update the packages, I wonder what the actual changes are and how they affect my projects, but I have no clue where to look it up.
Of course, I could search github for each package, find out the package version (not to mix up with the release version!) and look into the changelog, but this seems very cumbersome. Isn't there a unified Changelog for those burst-releases?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291477/where-to-find-info/changelogs-of-ros-package-releases/) by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2018-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Isn't there a unified Changelog for those burst-releases?

No, unfortunately not.

It would also not be trivial to do that, as packages are (mostly) developed in relative isolation, so it would take additional effort to create such a unified changelog.

Coalescing changelogs could be done however by a job on the buildfarm fi, but that is currently not something that exists.

---

Edit:

> One can observe that they're released in "bursts", so a group of packages are released together.

just to clarify: the packages are only *synced* in aggregation, they are not released together. Package maintainers are free to release their packages at any time, but those newer versions will not appear in the public/main repository until they are moved there from the staging one.

See [ShadowRepository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository) for some background on this process.

---

Edit2:

> Of course, I could search github for each package, find out the package version (not to mix up with the release version!) and look into the changelog, but this seems very cumbersome.

just in case you didn't know: package wiki pages for released packages have a link to the changelog as well. That might be more efficient than trawling github repositories.

It's in the *Package Links* box on the right side of the page:

[image: image description]

The one for `roscpp` is [here](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/changelogs/roscpp/changelog.html) fi.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2018-05-17**:
Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there a single source summarizing the package version bumps that were (or are going to be) released? Then one could parse this one and aggregate the changelog data somehow.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
I think @tfoote has scripts for that which he uses to generate content for the syncs he announces on [ROS Discourse](https://discourse.ros.org) periodically.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-17**:
I'd like to invite you to post about this over at the [Quality category](https://discourse.ros.org/c/quality) of ROS Discourse. This could be something more people could be interested in.

**Comment by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) on 2018-05-17**:
done: https://discourse.ros.org/t/unified-changelog-report-for-synchronized-ros-package-releases/4810